# How to Set up Amazon EC2 with Nexenta OS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, solaris, zfs, nexenta

I want to use Nexenta os for testing purpose and really want to test it out over aws ec2. I couldnot find any Nexenta os ami's. So, i was wondering if there's any way to set up Nexenta os on aws ec2 as a custom os ??

Any heads up or solutions are very much welcome.
Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to install Nexenta on a Vmware ESX. And use http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vmimport/ to push into amazon. I've never tried, but it could work.